# Youtube API jQuery error

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I use get method and log the data then it show me this error. I used youtube v3 API. generate API-key many time but it won't work.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 29208476753 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=29208476753 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=29208476753"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 29208476753 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=29208476753 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

This is my code:

```
$.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
        part: 'snippet, id',
        q: q,
        type: 'video',
        key: 'AIzaSyBnJBfGjTZ5Jw2HjHCDfu3-WgdzNEOBjE'
    },
    function (data) {
        var nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
        var previousPafeToken = data.previousPafeToken;
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will recommend you to use *$ajax* better than *$get*, because you can specify more details in your request as headers, types, etc.
Secondly, maybe the problem is due to the dataType of the request which is **jsonp** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). This problem occurs because, sometimes there are AJAX limitations between domains.

```
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search";
        var args = "part=snippet, id" + "&q=Eminem" + "&type=video" + "&key=AIzaSyB570U5NhHu1V_mnOTRzZVBb8cstTAY7eI";
        $.ajax({
            type: "get"
            , url: url
            , dataType: "jsonp" 
            , data: args
            , success: function (data, textStatus, response) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for you effort.